# Puts wallpaper only on 9/10th parts of the screen, not on all of it

Tags: windows-8, wallpaper

Is there a software that would let me put a wallpaper on only, like 9/10th of the screen (horizontally)?

I have the taskbar on the side and I don't want wallpaper underneath it.

I'm on Windows 8. It could be freeware or paid.

Answer (score 2):

You can take your, candidate, wallpaper and add a bar, of whichever colour you like but probably black or white, of the desired proportion, that occupies the first/last 10% of the image, either overwriting that much or expanding the image size by that much.

You can do this by hand with any image editor, *[gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is free & great,* or with a little work tools such as [imagemagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/), *(also free)*, will let you write a batch file that will take one image as an input and generate your new one for you.